# Rodar jQuery no console em uma página que não tem jQuery

Tags: jquery, console

Muitas vezes, o jQuery é bem útil para tirar algumas estatísticas da página e outras *cositas*, é só fazer um `$('.elemento').each(callback)` e já dá pra começar a saber o que está acontecendo na página.

O problema é que isso conta com que a página esteja fazendo o *load* do jQuery; se não, não tem jeito, tem que ser JS puro.

Existe alguma maneira de *forçar* o carregamento do jQ em uma página qualquer, p.ex., o Google?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tem jeito sim, como podemos ver nesta resposta do SOen: [*Include jQuery in the JavaScript Console*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7474386/1287812).

É só fazer *paste* do código no console e o jQuery vai ser carregado. Podemos então usá-lo livremente no console. Ligeiramente adaptado:

```
var jq = document.createElement('script');
jq.src = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js";
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(jq);
// ... dar um tempinho pro script carregar
setTimeout( function(){
    jQuery.noConflict();
    $=jQuery;
    console.log('Carregado jQuery v' + $.fn.jquery);
}, 3000);
```

Para facilitar o uso do *snippet* podemos guardá-lo como um... *snippet*!, dentro das [próprias Ferramentas de Desenvolvedor do Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470711/chrome-developer-tools-what-is-snippets-support):

<kbd>[image: console snippets injecting jquery]</kbd>

Comment: Em vez do setTimeout, dá pra usar jq.onload = function...